# how to pass array object to a cursor in Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, toad

I have my java code like below:

```
oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor arrayDesc = new oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor("ARRAY_DESC", conectionObj);
oracle.sql.ARRAY sqlArray = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDesc, conectionObj, valueArray );   
_statement = (oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement) conectionObj.prepareCall("BEGIN ? := pkg_abc.getProd(?);END;");
_statement.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
_statement.setARRAY(2, sqlArray);
```

I want to check what the cursor is returning in SQL editor such as TOAD. So, please let me know how to pass for the arguement `sqlArray` object in TOAD.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how you can get this type of info in your editor but perhaps you have enough access to the db to create a table and modify pkg_abc.getProd to insert the cursor data into that table. Presumably you are (or were) trying to debug a problem and this would at least give you such access.